# Deleting stubborn \r in data frame and creating CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new in the field, and I am having problems getting rid of a mid-string \r in a pandas data frame that I need to export into a CSV file.

Context: I had a CSV file that I downloaded as a report from the database platform we use in my organization. The report is legible to humans, not to computers, so there is all sort of merging, page breaks, and lots of other formatting. I need to clean it to create a SQL database. One of the columns has an ID number that appears divided into two lines when I see it in Excel:

[This is how the original CSV looks when viewed in Excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yEsZ.jpg)

I have tried to delete that separation, but I can't do it. When imported as a DataFrame, Python points out there is an "\r" mid-string - like below:

150043\r35

So this is what I have done:

I imported the CSV file:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Assessment.csv", header=None)
```

I attempted this:

```
df.replace("\r\n","", regex=True)
```

And this:

```
df.replace("\r","", regex=True)
```

After both attempts, it seemed that \r had disappeared in the data frame, like below:

```
15004335
```

However, when I create a new CSV, it keeps separating the lines:

This is how it looks even after using the replace function:

[image]

In the text editor, it looks like this:

```
,0,1,6,8,13,15,20,27

0,,,,,Student ID: ,150043

35,,

1,Student:,...
```

How do I get rid of this permanently? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you assigning the result of the replace back to the initial DF, or doing inplace=True to make the changes "stick"? Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] in the text of your question, not as a picture or link, and with a _reproducible amount of code_ showing the steps you're actually taking

Comment: Just with your first question you helped me solve my issue. I was not doing that. Thank you so much for your time! Got lots to learn!